# How to combine object key/value into single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript object with several keys whose values are arrays of objects. I am trying to combine all key/values into a single array of objects. So from

```
{
    a: [{}, {}, {}],
    b: [{}, {}, {}],
    c: [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

To

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ...]
```

I am trying something like

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(key => myObject[key])
```

Which results in an array with 3 arrays inside.

I have also tried using using lodash and doing

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(key => _.values(myObject[key]))
```

Which seems to result in the same thing. How can I properly do this? Preferably in a single line like I am attempting instead of a loop. Sorry if this is asked already, I don't know how to word the question to find a result

Comment: Single array of objects like mentioned in question. Edited question to visually show desired result also

Comment: do you just want to omit keys, a,b,c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to generate an array with all the nested objects (only one level of nesting is handled here, I don't know how much you want).

```
var values = {
    a: [{}, {}, {}],
    b: [{}, {}, {}],
    c: [{}, {}, {}]
};

Object.keys(values).reduce(function(res, key) {
    return res.concat(values[key]);
}, []); // [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: save some typing by using arrow function and `concat` instead (inside the reduce), eg: `reduce( (current, item) => current.concat( values[item] ) )`

Answer (score 4):

You could [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the values of the object.

```js
var object = { a: [{}, {}, {}], b: [{}, {}, {}], c: [{}, {}, {}] },
    array = [].concat(...Object.values(object));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Indeed, `Object.values()` is better here :)

Comment: Not supported in ie, [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Dhaval, the question has an arrow function inside, so op is using ES6.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, if keys are known, you can simply do:

```
const array = [...obj.a, ...obj.b, ...obj.c];
```

Comment: This would imply knowing the keys in advance, though.

Comment: Right. Good suggestion but I wont always know the keys

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate arrays in JavaScript. Here is a solution to your question:

```
var data = {
    a: [{}, {}, {}],
    b: [{}, {}, {}],
    c: [{}, {}, {}]
}

var result = [];

for (var key in data ){
   result = result.concat(data [key]);
}

console.log(result);
```